# Scope of Parallel.Foreach MaxDegreeOfParallelism

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm using Parallel.Foreach to process multiple concurrent tasks.I have limited the number of concurrent operations by specifying MaxDegreeOfParalellism. So now if i start another task outside of that foreach ,would max concurrent operations limit be applied on that task.

```
Parallel.ForEach(tasks, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MaxInstances }, task=>
                    {////Some OPeration///}


Task.Factory.StartNew(action)
```

If max limit is 8 and 8 concurrent tasks are already running in the Foreach.Would the task outside of foreach run?

Comment: In the given sample, the task would run, because at the time it is started, the parallel foreach is done and all of its tasks are completed.

Comment: I mean to say that if a separate thread tries to execute a task outside of foreach while foreach is being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the options you apply to a `Parallel.ForEach()` affect only that `Parallel.ForEach()`, they don't directly affect any other code.

(Actually, the more you limit the `Parallel.ForEach()`, the more likely it is that the other `Task` will execute immediately. This is because your `Parallel.ForEach()` will use less threads from the `ThreadPool`, leaving more of them free for others.)

Comment: so how can i set the threadpool limit for all tasks whether inside parallel.foreach or outside of it.?

Comment: It's likely not a good idea, but you can do it by calling [`ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads). What would be the right solution depends on why are you trying to do it.